# Weak derivative of logarithm function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to calculate the weak derivative of the function

$$u(x)=\log\log\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)$$

where $x \in B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$. I know that

$$\nabla u(x)=-\frac{1}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}\frac{x}{|x|^2} = -\frac{x}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)|x|(|x|+1)}$$

but I need check this from the definition of a weak derivative.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Away from the origin you have the theorem that the general theorem that the weak derivative of a differentiable function is the classical derivative. At the origin you have some more work to do. You also might specify the dimension of the space in your problem. (Evans uses your example to prove that $W^{1,2}$ of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not embed into $L^\infty$, but $W^{1,2}$ of an interval *does* embed into $L^\infty$, so the situation here depends on the dimension.)

Comment: @Ian thanks for your answer! The dimension is equal n, n > 1.

Comment: I am using this function like a conterexample to the same thing that Evans did. But now in dimension n.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the domain has to be smaller than the unit ball, otherwise the function has a singularity at $|x|=\frac1{e-1}<1$.

I choose $B(0,1/e)$.

---

Take a smooth test function $\phi\in C_0^\infty(B(0,1/e))$. You need to verify
$$
\int_{B_1} u \nabla \phi = - \int_{B_1} \nabla u \phi
$$
with $\nabla u$ given by your formula.

The trick is to integrate over $B(0,1/e)\setminus B(0,\epsilon)$, $\epsilon\in(0,1/e)$ first, then let $\epsilon\searrow 0$.
Set $A_\epsilon:=B(0,1/e)\setminus B(0,\epsilon)$, $\Gamma_\epsilon:=\partial B(0,\epsilon)$.
Due to integration by parts (everything is smooth here!)
$$
\int_{A_\epsilon} u \nabla \phi = -\int_{A_\epsilon} \nabla u \phi 
+ \int_{\Gamma_\epsilon} u \phi n,
$$
where $n$ is the outer normal vector, here $n(x) = -\frac{x}{|x|}$.

You need to verify that $u,\nabla u\in L^1(B(0,1/e))$, which can be done using polar coordinates. Then the first two integrals converge for $\epsilon\searrow 0$.

Then you have to verify that the boundary integral converges to zero, which amounts to proving that
$$
\epsilon^{n-1}\log\log(1+\epsilon^{-1}))\to 0.
$$

---

To see that $\nabla u$ is in $L^1$, note that one can estimate
$$
|\nabla u|\le \frac1{|\log(1+|x|^{-1})|}.
$$
Then integrate this on $B_{1/e}(0)$ to get
$$
\int_0^{1/e} \frac{ r^{n-1}}{|\log(1+r^{-1})|} \le \int_0^{1/e} \frac{r^{n-1}}{|\log(1+e)|}<\infty.
$$
Similarly, one shows $u\in L^1$.

Comment: How can I prove that $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_0^\varepsilon r^{n-1}\log\log (1 + r^{-1})dr = 0$$ can you help me??

Comment: The log-term is monotone, hence $\log\log(1+r^{-1})\le \log\log(1+\epsilon^{-1}))$.

Comment: But the log-term is monotone decreasing, so $\log\log(1+r^{-1}) \geq \log\log(1+\varepsilon^{-1})$, does not it?

Comment: Log is increasing on positive numbers, hence we have $r\le 1/e$, $1/r \ge e$, $\log(1+1/r)\ge \log(1+e) > 1$, $\log\log(1+r^{-1})\ge\log\log(1+e) >0$, and $\frac1{\log\log(1+r^{-1})} \le \frac1{\log\log(1+e) }$.